# Distribution of James-Stein estimator

Tags: regularization, estimators, james-stein-estimator

For reference, I'm working with something like

$${\mathbf Y} \sim N_d({\boldsymbol \mu}, \sigma^2 I)$$

We can estimate $\boldsymbol\mu$ using the JSE

$$ \widehat{\boldsymbol \theta}_{JS} = 
\left( 1 - \frac{(d-2) \sigma^2/n}{\|{\mathbf {\bar{Y}_n}}\|^2} \right) {\mathbf {\bar{Y}_n}}.$$

Then what is the distribution of $\widehat{\boldsymbol \theta}_{JS}$? Has anyone calculated it for any of the useful shrinkage estimators?